# Is OK to enclosing all values in SQL statement with single quotes?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Is it ok to enclose all values in SQL statement with single quotes ? For example:

This is simple table called books:

```
id  |  title
1   |  Some book name
2   |  Second book name
```

Is it OK to write statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = '1'
```

I've tested that query in SQL server 2008 and MySQL 5 and it works good, but I am curious is there any performance issue, because ID field is acctualy integer.

And second question is it OK to write statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = N'1'
```

N prefix is used in SQL server for UTF-8 fields, but I've tested that in SQL server and MySQL and both worked OK. I don't know if SQLite support N prefix, because I didn't test that.

The reason why I am asking this is because I am building database class that will work with popular SQL databases (SQL Server, MySQL, SQLite and maybe MS Access), so when performing selecting, inserting or updating data I don't have to worry about field datatype. I can always enclose value with N'Some value', but I am curious is this correct and is there any performance issues?

Comment: I am completely lost. You `don't have to worry about field datatype`? So that means validation goes right out the window then?

Comment: When building a mutlidatabase ORM (or whatever you wish to call it), you'll need to support different syntaxes just as a matter of course. Might as well start with that in mind - also, remember that SQLite has typed values and only loose column [type affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: (Of course, when using placeholders/prepared statements - which every respectable database adapter should support - the syntax wrt. quoting is largely irrelevant, even if type conversions may still apply.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can get an implicit conversion when doing this. Sometimes it won't affect the plan or have noticeable impacts on performance, but sometimes it might. They are generally deemed to be bad. Inspect the plans for these two queries against AdventureWorks2012:

```
SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader WHERE SalesOrderID = 43659;

SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader WHERE SalesOrderID = '43659';
```

The latter contains a `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` (hover over the tooltip for the CI seek).

You also want to be very careful about switching between `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` - in some cases this can be dreadful for performance, depending on the underlying data type and whether the literal has the `N` prefix.

Long story short: don't do this. Write your ORM thingy so that it understands the different data types and handles them appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT ... WHERE int_type = '123'` is fine to do. SQL will convert `'123'` to an integer once and be done with it.

However, `SELECT ... WHERE char_type = 123` is no okay, because SQL will have to convert every cell into an integer. See that char_type = '0123' and char_type = '00123' will also match. So it has to do more work.

Thanks to @MartinSmith for pointing out a resource for precedence in casting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx

Comment: This can happen the other way around, too.

Comment: Should probably mention [Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) which explains which way round the implicit casts will go.

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224021%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html) both perform implicit type conversions, but it doesn't make it a good practice; use the appropriate native type when you can.  This will let you avoid trying to spot the difference between:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = '1'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = 'l'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = 'O'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = '0'
```

(that's a one, a lower case L, a capital 'o', and a zero respectively)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example bug in MySQL that says the implicit typecast from quoted string of digits to an integer causes a severe performance issue:  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43319

It's best to *not* quote numbers.